# jQuery update PHP var on select menu value change

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So I'm using PHP to parse though XML files and display titles to different stories. I have a select menu that filters the stories based on the company. I have this working, but it refreshes the page. Could someone provide me an example of how to do this via Ajax so the entire page doesn't refresh? Any help is appreciated.

Live example: http://recoverstudio.com/test/

Current code:

```
<form name="feed-form" action="" method="GET">
  <select name="feed" onchange="this.form.submit();">
    <option value="">Filter</option>
    <option value="https://www.pitchengine.com/Feed/AgencyRss/036d17f9-50ff-4cf1-9273-8865ba82d9ff">All</option>
    <option value="http://pitchengine.com/Feed/BrandRss/cf6f4ba5-5e43-47c8-a7f2-1a9cb490c639">Brand 1</option>
  </select>
</form>

<div id="press-releases"> 
    <div id="pitch-engine">
    <?php
        $url = 'https://www.pitchengine.com/Feed/AgencyRss/036d17f9-50ff-4cf1-9273-8865ba82d9ff';
        if(isset($_GET['feed'])){
            $url = $_GET['feed'];
        }
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

        echo '<table>';
        echo '<tr class="head"><td>Date</td><td>Title</td></tr>';
        foreach($xml->channel->item as $item)
        {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . $item->pubDate . '</td>';
            echo '<td><a href="' . $item->link . '">' . $item->title  . '</a></td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>';
    ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to make an AJAX call on the jQuery `.change` event.

Something like this should do it (untested):

```
$('#myselect').change(function() {
    var url = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        type:'GET',
        success: function (res) {
            // res should contain your XML string - parse it
        }
        error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
            console.log(status+' - '+errorThrown);
            alert('Something went wrong processing the request.');
        }
    });   
});
```

You can probably sort out the XML parsing yourself - I only have experience parsing JSON with javascript.